Why is the standardized ECDSA conversion function projection instead of a hash function?
DSA/ECDSA has not been shown to be provably secure when H alone is modeled as an RO (Random Oracle). However, Brickell showed as far back as 1996 ([2], I couldn't actually find his Brickell96 citation) that the schemes are provably secure in the ROM if they are modified so that the conversion function, f, is a hash function (and thus can be modeled as an RO) instead of just projection onto the x-axis.
There are other provably secure variants as well. IEEE didn't standardize ECDSA until 2000, so why wasn't this taken into account? ISO was apparently aware of a provably secure variant prior to '98 as they mentioned one in their 14888 report (according to 1, I can't actually view the standard because it costs money). Was there actually some sound reasoning that has been lost to the ages on why three standards bodies ignored a small modification that would render the scheme provably secure?
I understand that any answers to this question will probably be highly speculative, but if anyone actually knows something about the ECDSA standardization process then please share.
[1]: Brickell, Ernest, Pointcheval, David, Vaudenay, Serge, & Yung, Moti. (2000). Design Validations for Discrete Logarithm Based Signature Schemes.
[2]: PKC 2021 invited talk from Eike Kiltz https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96I2wHr8uKE

I'm puzzled: in this 2016 work, didn't Eike Kiltz claim "that forging signatures in (EC)DSA is as hard as solving discrete logarithms" ? And now states "a meaningful security proof for ECDSA is unlikely to exist without strong idealization" ? Update: perhaps the gap in the earlier proof was that it assumed the adversary does not have access to signatures.

@fgrieu The 2016 work uses a strong idealization. Namely "It carefully models the "modulo q" conversion function of (EC)DSA as a composition of three independent functions. The two outer functions mimic algebraic properties in the function's domain and range, the inner one is modeled as a bijective random oracle." So there's no contradiction here.
